# set value in input type file multiple

Tags: angular, file, input, filelist

How do I make a set value in an input of the type file I bring the files from my server and I want to assign it to the input so that when I click on the edit button I get the images it has and work with them I'm working with Angular.

```
  this.dashboard_form?.patchValue({ 
      type: value[0]?.tipo,
      category: value[0]?.categoria,
      image: this.archives (array files),
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I only answered this, reading around there you can't alter the filelist you can't programmatically fill it all would be very vulnerable now that I think about it. It still brings me doubts about how to edit a product and show the images. I imagine that with a dropzone or something similar you could make a patch value

Comment: Hi, please Edit the question instead of creating an answer when providing information